# Gloobus-preview won' t play any video and audio (ubuntu 12.04 on mbp)

Tags: gloobus-preview

My newly installed gloobus won' t load video or audio files. It can load mp4 video but only outputs the audio, it won' t show any image from the video file. It used to work fine on a previews install of 12.04 on the same machine. It can still preview images though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED! I just had to let movie player download codecs to support video and audio formats when trying to open those videos with movie player. 
or via terminal run this command

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 gstreamer0.10-gnonlin gstreamer0.10-sdl gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse gstreamer0.10-schroedinger gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly totem-plugins-extra
```